# finding probabillity for average value ( continous density function)

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Suppose i have a continuos density function for a random variable x as such( function describes runtime for a program in seconds if it means anything):

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{3}{64}\right)x^2(4-x) & \text{for } 0 < x < 4 \\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

First I needed to find the probability for $p( x < 2)$ which is $0.3125$.

Now I'm asked, if you run the program 40 times, what is the probability that the average runtime for these 40 times is smaller than 2.
I tried using the central limit theorem but i cant  seem to get to the correct answer (which is $0.0008$). so help with finding an approach would help a lot.

Comment: Actually CLT seems to give you $7.8 \times 10^{-4}$ which is reasonably correct, I think it depends on how you approximate in your calculations.

Comment: Well, closest i have gotten is 7.8*10^(-3) . how did you get this result?

Comment: I simply computed mean and variance and proceed with standard CLT, last step I had was $N(-\sqrt{10})=7.8 \times 10^{-4}$

Comment: which mean and variance? what distribution did you calculate it for?

Comment: For the distribution you specified I get mean=$\frac{12}{5}$ and variance=$\frac{32}{5}$, I used the relation $\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^{2}]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^{2}$

Comment: Thanks, i undertand now.